# Pagination with ItemsCollection#query?

Tags: ruby, amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb

Currently, the ItemCollection#query method in the Ruby AWS SDK returns the whole dataset. I looked into the Ruby AWS SDK source code for any possibility of pagination, but the option closest to pagination is `:limit`, no pagination. According to the Amazon's DynamoDB API (the HTTP, not Ruby) documentation for Query operation suggests there COULD be pagination with the response key `LastEvaluatedKey`:

> Primary key of the item where the query operation stopped, inclusive of the previous result set. Use this value to start a new operation excluding this value in the new request.
>   The LastEvaluatedKey is null when the entire query result set is complete (i.e. the operation processed the “last page”).

So I can do paging by adding the `:limit` option, and then doing the next query for a range value after my last `Item`, but then I have no idea what the total count is unless I do a full query.

Is there a better/easier way of achieving pagination?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Depending on your needs, building a complete pager will likely require two requests, see [Query and Scan in Amazon DynamoDB](http://docs.amazonwebservices.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/QueryAndScan.html), in particular [Count and ScannedCount](http://docs.amazonwebservices.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/QueryAndScan.html#Count):

> The Amazon DynamoDB Scan and Query APIs use Count values for two
>   distinct purposes.
>
> **In a request**, set the Count parameter to true if you want Amazon
>   DynamoDB to **provide the total number of items** that match the scan
>   filter or query condition, **instead of a list of the matching items**.
>
> **In a response**, Amazon DynamoDB returns a Count value for the number of
>   matching items in a request. **If the matching items for a scan filter
>   or query condition is over 1MB, Count contains a partial count of the
>   total number of items that match the request**. To get the full count of
>   items that match a request, use the LastEvaluatedKey in a subsequent
>   request. Repeat the request until Amazon DynamoDB no longer returns a
>   LastEvaluatedKey.
>
> *[emphasis mine]*

That is, to avoid complicated logic initially you'll likely want to query the number of matching items upfront and request specific pages on demand thereafter only.

Good luck!

Comment: I was afraid this was the case. Since I'm using the Ruby SDK, do you have any insight whether the #query method can achieve this? I've tried adding a `count: true` option, but it still returns an `Enumerator`.

Comment: @JohnK.Chow: Irritating indeed - I do not use Ruby much outside of DevOps topics, hence haven't tried this myself; the API docs for [ItemCollection](http://docs.amazonwebservices.com/AWSRubySDK/latest/AWS/DynamoDB/ItemCollection.html) actually do not list a `count` parameter for `#query` indeed, rather only a dedicated `#count` method, supposedly counting _the items in the collection using a table scan_, which strikes me as odd given the cost/performance characteristics of [Scan](http://docs.amazonwebservices.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/API_Scan.html) - might be a doc bug though?

Comment: The query API can only count records with the same hash key value, is that what you want?  The only way to count "all records" is with scan.

Comment: @SteffenOpel I did see the `#count` method, which drove me crazy because of exactly what you said.


@TrevorRowe Indeed, I only want to get the count of all items for the hash key, but the Ruby SDK doesn't seem to have that option. I'd like to open an issue on their Github repo, but they don't have it open... Not a deal breaker, but definitely annoying.

Comment: @JohnK.Chow You can use the enumeration to get the total count: t.items.query(:count => true, :hash_value => '1').inject(0){|total,count| total + count} -- The service can return partial counts with a "next token" for counting more.  The enumeration returns those partial counts.